# Error with fde12 multiple initial conditions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

When I am giving values of `alpha>1`, e.g., `alpha=1.05`, it gives error:

```
??? Error using ==> fde12 at 114
A not sufficient number of assigned initial conditions.
Order ALPHA = 1.050000 requires 2 initial conditions. See FDE12
```

When I give `y0` as a vector of 2 initial conditions, it gives erroneous output. The reason I think is that I am giving the initial conditions from the two values returned from ODE45 for the same set of parameters. I understand that the second initial condition must come iteratively from the `fde12` only, but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Format of y0 is given in function description (call `help fde12`):

> The set of initial conditions Y0 is a matrix with a number of rows
> equal to the size of the problem (hence equal to the number of rows of
> the output of FDEFUN) and a number of columns depending on ALPHA and
> given by m.
>
> where m is the smallest integer grater than ALPHA

E.g., you need row with two initial conditions instead vector (column).

Comment: The problem is that I have only one initial condition at the starting point. One initial condition is sufficient for solving equations with alpha<1 but not that for greater than 1. So how do I get those additional conditions?

Comment: fde12 method solve equation: "D^ALPHA Y(t) = FDEFUN(T,Y(T)),      Y^(k)(T0) = Y0(:,k+1), k=0,...,m-1, 
where m is the smallest integer grater than ALPHA and D^ALPHA is the fractional derivative according to the Caputo's definition." It seems that you can not select alpha value arbitrarily, but should set alpha based on initial equation. Try to look reference papers given in fde12 help.

Comment: That precisely answers my question. Thanks a lot.